# Visual Studio editor not showing any text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have been using VS for many years.  Today I have encountered a very strange problem with visual studio 2013. Suddenly for some reason I am unable to see any text in the editor window.  I've tried reloading the files, redocking each window, restarting VS, restarting my machine and resetting all my settings in Tools -> Import and Export Settings.  At present I'm completely stuck as I can't do anything.  The tab for each opened file appears at the top as expected but just a blue pane. I'm hoping this is something daft!

[image]

Comment: Any extensions or addins installed?

Comment: I've got resharper installed and MVVMLight

Comment: Blow me, I just uninstalled MVVMLight and it goes away.  thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was caused by the installation of MVVM Light via the extension manager. I uninstalled it and it went away. Installing the required dlls via nuget didn't have the same issue.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239417/code-editor-appears-blank#comment51148290_30239417, where there is a better solution

Answer (score 13):

I just had the same Problem. However MVVM Light is not installed. I deactivated all extensions that to my knowledge could interfere with the editor and restarted. Problem solved.
Then I reactivated the extensions bit by bit, now all are active again and the problem is still gone.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment

Comment: Then you should work on that, reputation is essential for the way this community works. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: I am glad it is not a comment. While it does not have any code in the answer, Following these steps helped me resolve my problems as well.

Comment: This may not be a "model" answer but it does resolve the underlying problem for some people (myself included) and can be considered an answer