# Visual Studio 2015 not displaying my code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I open up a pre-existing c# project in Visual Studio 2015 my code doesn't show, I can run the program from Visual Studio but cannot see or edit the code. I've tried repairing and re-installing and nothing seems to work

Comment: What's in solution explorer or you just didn't see solution explorer?

Comment: @qxg Forgot about solution explorer, problem fixed, thanks!

Comment: How about describing what you did to fix the problem????

Comment: @lmathurin : please can you tell us how did you fix the problem, i am facing the same issue. Ty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code editor appears blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239417/code-editor-appears-blank)

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by a corrupted Visual Studio cache.

Close all Visual Studio tasks that are running, and delete all files in the folders ComponentModelCache and MEFCacheBackup

these folders are located in:

\Users\YOUR_USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\YOUR_VISUAL_STUDIO_VERSION

-------------------- This was from the duplicate and it fixed my issue The MEFCacheBackup had files and when removed my VS worked great.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the same issue in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 when I installed the specific font `Cascadia Code` Microsoft provided.

After I reverted the code font to common used font (such as `Consolas`), the code can show successfully.

The related settings is below:

[image]

If you used an specific font for code, you can also try this method. May it be helpful for you.

Just enjoy.