# Visual Studio 2022: Recent projects window not launch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I just installed Visual Studio 2022. Everything is working fine, but strangely, it does not launch the "Recent Projects" window on start. It just opens the empty window.

Expected below Recent Projects window:

[image]

But it launch empty(as shown below screen shot):

[image]

Comment: Not sure If I had the same symptoms, but all problems were gone, after restarting the pc

Comment: I also re-started my pc twice. But still same behavior.

Comment: You could try this (Version 17), and restart PC again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38685242/2441442

Comment: I tried same, but not luck